# Specify color when plotting using Graphics

Tags: plotting

If I have the following:

```
p1 = ListPlot[data];
p2 = Graphics@Line[{{65, 0.056}, {80, 0.056}}];
```

How can I plot both p1 and p2 together specifying the color for each of them. For instance, I want `p1` to be green and `p2` to be red. I am using the following

```
Show[{p1, p2}, PlotStyle -> {Green, Red}]
```

but this does not work for those colors.

EDIT: How can I add legends for each of them? say "legend1" for the `p1` and "legend2" for the `p2`

Thanks,

Comment: `ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Green]` and `Graphics[{Red, Line[...]}]` should do it. You can't use `Show` to do styling, it's just for putting graphics together. Note that `ListPlot` also has `Epilog` and `Prolog` options that you can use to draw the line.

Comment: @C.E. Thanks! I am using `p1=ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Green]` `p2 = Graphics[{Red, Line[{65, 0.056}, {80, 0.056}]}]` but It still does not work. Is there any sintax error in `p2`?. Finally I use `Show[p1, p2]`

Comment: Yes, it should be `Line[{{65, 0.056}, {80, 0.056}}]`

Comment: @C.E. Thank you! That works !

Comment: @C.E. last question: If I want to add a lengend for each of them. How can I do that?. I updated the question to reflect that as well.

Comment: @C.E.:  To be fair, some options that users might mentally lump in with "styling" (`PlotRange`, `Axes`, `PlotLabel`, `Ticks`, etc.) can be passed to `Show` as options.  So I wouldn't say that it's strictly true that `Show` is "just for putting graphics together".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = Transpose[{Range[60, 80], Sin[N@Range[60, 80]]}];


ListLinePlot[
 {data, {{65, 0.056}, {80, 0.056}}},
 PlotStyle -> {Green, Red},
 PlotLegends -> {"legend1", "legend2"}
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks!!! This works !

Comment: Good! Always glad to help. =)